# Debugging hadoop file requirement

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

I have a file that is about 1gb in size and about `19955931` line long, when I pipe it into hadoop it returns empty data.

However if I created a new file using head with the same amount of line

```
head -19955931 my.log > my_new_copy.log
```

Hadoop returns the correct non empty data.

I am completely perplexed by this behavior, is hadoop expecting a specific meta file format?

Comment: What does `$ wc -l <filename>` report?

Comment: What is the command that you're using to put data into HDFS

Comment: @JagrutSharma `wc -l my.log` reports `19955931` that is how i find how many lines is there in the file

Comment: @Abhinav the files are all in s3, so hadoop reads the s3 path

Comment: Try checking the number of lines in file uploaded to S3. `$ hadoop fs -cat s3n://bucket/my.log | wc`